# How to use events in GWT Frame

Tags: events, gwt, frame

I would like to capture all events within a GWT frame. I've found several ways to do this, but they only return mousemove and mouseout events. I also need keypresses, input, etc. The goal is to capture the events and send them to another client by using websockets, and then replicate them on the other side (co-browsing).

I am using a page on the same domain within the frame.

```
public class ESinkFrame extends Frame implements EventListener { 

    public ESinkFrame(String src){ 
          super(src); 

      DOM.sinkEvents(getElement(), Event.KEYEVENTS);
      DOM.sinkEvents(getElement(), Event.MOUSEEVENTS);
    } 

    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) { 
          System.out.println( "sunk event: " + DOM.eventGetTypeString(event) ); 
    } 
}
```

And when I use it, I also try to attach a different way of grabbing the events.

```
ESinkFrame frame = new ESinkFrame("http://127.0.0.1:8888/other.html");

RootPanel.get().add(frame);


FrameElement frameElt = frame.getElement().cast();
Document frameDoc = frameElt.getContentDocument();
BodyElement body = frameDoc.getBody();
Element el = body.cast();

DOM.setEventListener(el, new EventListener()
{
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event)
        {
            Window.alert("test");
        }

});
DOM.sinkEvents(el, Event.KEYEVENTS);

Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler(){
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        String eventName = event.getNativeEvent().getType();
        if (event.isFirstHandler() /* && (event.getTypeInt() & Event.MOUSEEVENTS) == 0*/)
        System.out.println("PreviewHandler: " + eventName);
        }
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippets in your question.

Comment: I've added the 2 ways in which I've tried to solve the problem